# Marklogic collate sequence in XQuery

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is there a way to modify the elements a sequence so only collated versions of the items are returned?

```
let $currencies := ('dollar', 'Dollar', 'dollar ')
return fn:collated-only($currencies, "http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/T00BB/AS")

=> ('dollar', 'dollar', 'dollar')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these values are in XML elements and you have a range index using `http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/T00BB/AS`, you can do something like this:

```
let $ref := cts:element-reference(xs:QName("currency"), "collation=http://marklogic.com/collation/en/S1/T00BB/AS")
for $curr in cts:values($ref, (), "frequency-order")
return $curr || ": " || cts:frequency($curr)
```

This will produce results like:

```
"dollar: 15",
"euro: 12"
```

... and so on. The collation will disregard the differences among your sample inputs. These results could be formatted however you want. Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: This works perfectly and is based on the same collation rule so it's less risky. In combination with the other answers I learned a few tricks today.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The values that are stored in the range index (that feeds the facets) are literally the first value that was encountered that compared equal to the others. (Because, the collation says you don't care...)

You can get a long way by calling 
`fn:replace(fn:lower-case(xdmp:diacritic-less(fn:normalize-unicode($str,"NFKC"))),"\p{P}","")`

This won't be exactly the same in that it overfolds some things and underfolds others, but it may be good for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks this will get me the result I was looking for but I would have have been nice to use the same collation namespace string to ensure I was selecting the same values. Finding a count of currencies using XQuery is quite tricky.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the expected output? There is no fn:collated-only function, so I'm assuming you're asking how to write such a function or whether there is such a function.

The thing is, there isn't a mapping from one string to another in collation comparisons, there is only a comparison algorithm ([the Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/)) so there really is no canonical kind of string to return to you, and therefore no API to do so.

Stepping back, what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? By the rules of that collation, "dollar" and "Dollar" are equivalent, and by using it you declare you don't care which form you use, so you could use either one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. What I was trying to do was produce some output in xquery and then reproduce using search:search facets. I used fn:distinct-values and then counted matching nodes. The answers did not match so I realised I was comparing the wrong thing. I figured if fn:distinct exists there must be some equivilant for reducing the variety in a sequence.